# MongoDB, sort the results by the number of matching elements between two arrays

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In my project I use MongoDB as a database (specifically the mongoose driver for typescript, but this shouldn't matter) and I have a collection of posts that follow this schema:

```
export const PostSchema = new Schema({
  author: { type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'User' },
  text: { type: String, required: true },
  tags: [{ type: Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Tag' }],
  location: { type: PointSchema, required: true },
}

export const PointSchema = new Schema({
  type: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['Point'],
    required: true,
  },
  coordinates: {
    type: [Number],
    required: true,
  },
  locationName: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});
```

My question is if it is possible to write a query (I think an aggregation is needed) that returns all posts that meet a condition (such as that the position must be at a specific distance) and orders the results by a specific array of tags passed as an argument (in my case the array varies from user to user and represents their interests).
That is, choosing the array ["sport", "music", "art"] as an example, I would like a query that retrieves from the database all the posts that meet a certain condition (irrelevant in this question) and orders the results so that first are documents whose array of tags share elements with the array ["sport", "music", "art"], and only at the end the documents without any correspondence.
That is, something like this:

```
[
{
  _id: "507f191e810c19729de860ea",
  tags: ["sport", "art", "tennis"] // 2 matches
},
{
  _id: "507f191e810c1975de860eg",
  tags: ["sport", "food"] // 1 matches
},
{
  _id: "607f191e810c19729de860ea",
  tags: ["animals", "art"] // 1 matches
},
{
  _id: "577f191e810c19729de860ea",
  tags: ["animals", "zoo"] //0 matches
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your collection looks like this:

```js
[
    {
        "author": "John",
        "tags": [
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e2"), // Sport
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e8"), // Music
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e5"), // Food
        ]
    },
    {
        "author": "Dheemanth",
        "tags": [
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e7"), // Tech
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e5"), // Food
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e2")  // Sport
        ]
    },
    {
        "author": "Niccolo",
        "tags": [
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e2"), // Sport
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e8"), // Music 
            ObjectId("60278ce8b370ff29b83226e3")  // Art
        ]
    }
]
```

then this is the solution:

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "tags",
      let: { "tags": "$tags" },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$tags"] }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "tags"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "tagCount": {
        $size: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$tags",
            as: "tag",
            cond: { $in: ["$$tag.name", ["sport", "music", "art"]] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: { tagCount: -1 }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      tags: "$tags.name"
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60278e14b370ff29b83226eb"),
    "tags": ["sport", "art", "music"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60278e14b370ff29b83226e9"),
    "tags": ["sport", "food", "music"]
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60278e14b370ff29b83226ea"),
    "tags": ["sport", "food", "tech"]
  }
]
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you so much,  you saved my day! As for efficiency, do you think this is an acceptable operation on a large scale?